# How do you convert a Ruby hash to a Javascript object with unquoted values?

Tags: javascript, ruby

I want to output a Ruby hash as a JS object but for some values of the hash I need them without quotes, i.e. JS code. For example (something like) this Ruby:

```
{ foo: proc { 'someJavascriptFn()' } }.to_json
```

Would output this JS:

```
{ foo: someJavascriptFn() }
```

Is something like this possible without patching `proc` or `hash`?

Comment: *"... as a JS object (or JSON)..."* No, not JSON. That output is invalid JSON.

Comment: Fixed, removed json.

Comment: If you need to call the function directly, you can use JS `eval()`. Just be careful and heed the warnings here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/eval 

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, this is possible, but you’ll need to build JSON yourself:

```
hash = {
  foo: proc { 'someJavascriptFn()' },
  bar: 42,
  baz: "Hello, world!"
}

content = hash.each_with_object([]) do |(k, v), acc|
  acc << ("#{k}: " << (Proc === v ? v.() : v.inspect))
end.join(",\n")
#⇒ "foo: someJavascriptFn(),\nbar: 42,\nbaz: \"Hello, world!\""
puts "{#{content}}"
#⇒ {foo: someJavascriptFn(),
#   bar: 42,
#   baz: "Hello, world!"}
```

Please note, that you might need to implement recursive call to this function if your input has nested structures.